# Adding many models to another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently working on a small project using Ruby On Rails 3.2 to create a database that contains several unique Models. Each Model has many Elements and each Element has the potential to belong to many Models. I have been able to set up the models in the following manner:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_elements
  has_many :elements, :through => :model_elements
  attr_accessible :elements, :name, :notes, :ref
end

class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model_elements
  has_many :models, :through => :model_elements
  attr_accessible :elementType, :name, :notes, :ref
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class ModelElement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Model
  belongs_to :element
  attr_accessible :model_id, :created_at, :element_id
end
```

My question is how do I add multiple Elements to a single Model? I've tried to find some documentation but I can't find anything. Currently I'm trying to do the following:

```
@model.elements = @element
```

Where @element is a predefined element however it's throwing the following error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Element:0x007ff803066500>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
`@model.elements << @element`

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.create(attributes = {})
```

Returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated with attributes, linked to this object through the join table, and that has already been saved.

```
 @model.elements.create(:name => "example")
```

Answer (score 0):

Amar's answer is correct. If you wanted you can simplify your models further by using the has_and_belongs_to_many association.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :elements, :join_table => :model_elements
end

class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :models, :join_table => :model_elements
end

@model.elements << @element
```